# C++ immutable string container

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

Is there any standard immutable string container that encapsulate char* and nothing else? Usage will be for storing strings into vectors and using char arrays as objects.

The reason I do not want to use `std::string` is their overhead.

Comment: Why do you think/know that the overhead from std::string is a problem?

Comment: What overhead? Saving the length of the string? You need that anyways (or `strlen` in O(n) all the time). The 64 extra bit to save the capacity? On what system is that a problem?

Comment: If you really wanna do this (and I cannot possibly fathom *why* you would), `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`- go nuts.

Comment: If the strings are constants, just declare them as const char*.

Comment: Some `const shared_ptr<char *>` ?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? Why do you think std::string would have too much overhead? What sort of overhead do you think it has? Access time? Space? Construction time?

Comment: Doing in memory database. Also want to avoid in memory copy. Suppose I do add("bla"), string will copy the char array. This is why I use char *. But I will need to place this char * into vectors or other structures. I do notthink is premature optimization.

Comment: Don't be put off by the unhelpful comments. Std::string is in fact an extremely heavyweight class. It's not standard yet but boost has string_ref, howver you will have to make string copies anyway at some point

Comment: You can choose to use `const std::vector<char>` for a sized variable.and `const std::array<char, <N>>` for fixed sized `char` arrays not strings.i used to get them confused together.don't repeat the mistake i did!

Comment: @james boost::string_ref is what I need. Thanks. Pls dot it as answer.

Answer (score 4):

> *"The reason I do not want to use `std::string` is their overhead."*

Supposed that `std::string` doesn't have any *overhead* (unless you prove so in your question) it should be the right choice used as a `const std::string`.

Alternatively you might choose a `const std::vector<char>` for variable sized, or `const std::array<char,<N>>` for *`<N>`* fixed sized `char` arrays.

Comment: If `string` doesn't have overhead then `vector` doesn't either. In fact it's probably the dynamic allocation he wishes to avoid (which is reasonable) and only your latter suggestion allows that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, good point. That's why I've mentioned it.

Comment: Copying is overhead: say an immutable object can bump atomic ref-counter, the string copy will require (multiple) allocations.

Comment: Yet another thing. shared_ptr is an alternative but it will require custom compare for every set and map.